# Call to protected method Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller::generateUrl()

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, php-7.1, symfony-4.2

Recently I am upgrading the system to Symfony 4.2, in one of my page, I encountered the error saying

```
Call to protected method Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller::generateUrl() from context 'Acme\Bundle\Security\Listener\SecurityListener'
```

The line at which the error is showing:

```
$this_url = $controller[0]->generateUrl($event->getRequest()->get('_route'), $event->getRequest()->get('_route_params'));
```

Please let me know, is there anything that I have left.

Comment: Protected methods are only visible within the class instance, which means you cannot use them from outside the class.  It is possible to use them with Reflection, but its not advisable.

Comment: What is the content of `$controller`?

Comment: If you extend the class you can use it, but should it extend the class with the method.

Comment: SecurityListener.php on line 45:
array:2 [▼
  0 => AcmeController {#583 ▼
    -country_name: array:249 [▶]
    +email_sender: array:1 [▶]
    #container: appAppKernelDevDebugContainer {#460 …20}
  }
  1 => "acmeAction"
]
This is the content of the Controller @D4V1D

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix I did found the url https://api.symfony.com/master/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/ControllerTrait.html#method_generateUrl but trait cannot be extended. Please check.

Comment: I didn't realize it's a trait, Im not a symfony user, you can rename the trait's method. then write your own with the original name, and reference the renamed trait method from witin your (public) method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to call the controller helper method from a listener. As @ArtisticPhoenix has said in the comments, this is not allowed. What you could do here is instead rewrite your listener to use not the controller's method (which is just intended to be a helper for your actions), but the actual router method that generates the URL. Take a look at the `Controller` (or `ControllerTrait` depending on your Symfony version). The `generateUrl()` method makes a call on the `@router` service:

```
/**
 * Generates a URL from the given parameters.
 *
 * @see UrlGeneratorInterface
 *
 * @final
 */
protected function generateUrl(string $route, array $parameters = [], int $referenceType = UrlGeneratorInterface::ABSOLUTE_PATH): string
{
    return $this->container->get('router')->generate($route, $parameters, $referenceType);
}
```

That's what you actually have to use instead of calling the controller's method. You could try something like this:

```
$this_url = $this->container->get('router')->generate($event->getRequest()->get('_route'), $event->getRequest()->get('_route_params'));
```

Although, you'd have to make sure you either have the container available (which in general is not a good pattern), or you pass the `Router` into your service as a dependency. This way, you'd change `$this->container->get('router')` to the prop you're injecting the router into.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to generate an url in your Listener, you can simply inject the router component to you class :

```
private $router;

public function __construct(UrlGeneratorInterface $router)
{
    $this->router = $router;
}

...

// Use it like this

$url = $this->router->generate(
    $event->getRequest()->get('_route'),
    $event->getRequest()->get('_route_params')
);
```